# Why does this JavaScript animation only work for one element despite same code for each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to build a simple game. A ball will come down and hit a bar, but you have to try to hit the ball on the color that the ball basically is. Well to move the ball you have to click 2 different arrows. One for moving left and one for moving right. They both work but for some reason when the right arrow is clicked more than once, the left arrow does nothing when clicked, thus not allowing the ball to move back anymore left. This problem only occurs on the right side, not the left.
 
HTML

```
<div class='cont'>
  <h1 class='title'>Culor</h1>
  <div class='ball-cont'>
    <div class='ball'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='slider'>
    <div class='arLeft ar'>
      <img class='leftAr' src=''>
    </div>
    <div class='arRight ar'>
      <img class='rightAr' src=''>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
var main = function() {
  var ball = $('.ball');
//LEFT N RIGHT
  $('.arLeft').click(function(){
    ball.animate({
      right:'+=25px'
    });
  });

  $('.arRight').click(function(){
    ball.animate({
      left:'+=25px'
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

FULL CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/xstrgy3p/

Comment: Use `left:'-=25px'` instead of `right:'+=25px'`.

Answer (score 3):

Change `right: '+=25px'` to `left: '-=25x'`

Comment: Xufox beat me to it, evidently.